# Не запускается приложение Java Vulkan

Tags: java, vulkan

Я пытаюсь изучить Vulkan на Java. Скачал пример, запустил. Первые 2 класса запустились, показали белый лист. Ну, так и должно быть. Только последующие выдают ошибку:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Validation requested but not supported
at javavulkantutorial.Ch26DepthBuffering$HelloTriangleApplication.createInstance(Ch26DepthBuffering.java:444)
at javavulkantutorial.Ch26DepthBuffering$HelloTriangleApplication.initVulkan(Ch26DepthBuffering.java:313)
at javavulkantutorial.Ch26DepthBuffering$HelloTriangleApplication.run(Ch26DepthBuffering.java:276)
at javavulkantutorial.Ch26DepthBuffering.main(Ch26DepthBuffering.java:2102)

Я вообще не знаю, где есть решение, где найти гайды, как разобраться. Код брал отсюда https://github.com/Naitsirc98/Vulkan-Tutorial-Java?tab=readme-ov-file
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Бегло посмотрел код класса Ch26DepthBuffering.java.
Скорее всего vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties не возвращает в списке тот лайер, который вы запрашиваете.
Вам нужно настроить конфигурацию, где приложение будет искать слои\расширения